# Using glob in Yarn/NPM script

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

I'm using a script to run multiple files with Node.js using a glob pattern to capture the files:

```
node build/**/*.spec.js
```

This seems to work fine, but when I put the same command in the `scripts` object as follows

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node build/**/*.spec.js"
  }
```

and try to run it with `yarn test` or `npm run test` I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/project/build/**/*.spec.js'

indicating that it's treating the glob pattern as a literal filename.

How can I achieve the glob behaviour in a Yarn/NPM script?

Comment: I get the same result (_"Cannot find module"_) on the command line as running `npm t` (bash on macOS, Node 16.15.0, NPM 8.5.5). `npm run` [uses `/bin/sh`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script#script-shell), not your current shell (probably `zsh`, which _does_ work for me).

Comment: ah right, yes I'm using zsh which I guess interprets the glob pattern

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note here:

1. The behaviour of `node build/**/*.js` depends on your shell.

   - In `zsh` (the current default on macOS), it does what you expect; expanding the glob to all matching files and passing them to Node.
   - In `bash` and `sh`, it tries to run the literal file `build/**/*.js` with Node, which gives the *"Cannot find module"* error in your post.
2. The default shell used by `npm run-script` is, per [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script#script-shell):

   > '/bin/sh' on POSIX systems

   Even if you're using `zsh`, when you run the `test` script it uses `sh`. You can configure this with the `script-shell` option, e.g.:

   - in `.npmrc` (which you can update with `npm config set script-shell=/bin/zsh`); or
   - inline (by running `npm --script-shell=/bin/zsh test`).
3. However you get it running, note that only one of the matched files actually gets executed; the paths to the other two are passed as command line arguments. With three files `foo.spec.js`, `bar.spec.js` and `baz.spec.js` containing the following (adjusted to log each file's own name) in `build/`:

   ```js
   console.log(process.argv);
   console.log("foo");
   ```

   running the globbed version gives:

   ```sh
   $ node build/**/*.spec.js
   [
     '<path/to>/bin/node',
     '<path/to>/build/bar.spec.js',
     'build/baz.spec.js',
     'build/foo.spec.js'
   ]
   bar
   ```